# Flyway Future State prevents new migration

Tags: java, flyway

I'm trying the Java Migration tutorial. After modifying a migrated Java class, the Java class got stuck in Future state and prevented new migration. I'm new with Flyway and not sure where I did wrong. Or is there any known issue with Future state?

I first added two SQL files and ran mvn flyway:migrate. Both files are migrated successfully. Then added a Java class V3__Anonymize, ran mvn flyway:migrate again. It's successful too. The info command shows

```
+-----------+--------+---------------------+------+---------------------+---------+  
| Category  | Version| Description         | Type | Installed On        | State   |  
+-----------+--------+---------------------+------+---------------------+---------+  
| Versioned | 1      | Create person table | SQL  | 2022-11-03 08:26:52 | Success |  
| Versioned | 2      | Add people          | SQL  | 2022-11-03 08:28:45 | Success | 
| Versioned | 3      | Anonymize           | JDBC | 2022-11-03 09:05:29 | Success | 
+-----------+--------+---------------------+------+---------------------+---------+
```

Then I modified V3__Anonymize class, adding just a line to migrate function for System.out.println("something"). The info commands show this third job with a Future state:

```
+-----------+--------+---------------------+------+---------------------+---------+  
| Category  | Version| Description         | Type | Installed On        | State   |
+-----------+--------+---------------------+------+---------------------+---------+  
| Versioned | 1      | Create person table | SQL  | 2022-11-03 08:26:52 | Success | 
| Versioned | 2      | Add people          | SQL  | 2022-11-03 08:28:45 | Success | 
| Versioned | 3      | Anonymize           | JDBC | 2022-11-03 09:05:29 | Future  | +-----------+--------+---------------------+------+---------------------+---------+
```

Then ran mvn flyway:migrate, and it gave a WARNING shown below.

```
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:9.7.0:migrate (default-cli) @ my-migration-service ---
[INFO] Flyway Community Edition 9.7.0 by Redgate  
[INFO] See what's new here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#9.7.0 
[INFO]
[INFO] Database: jdbc:h2:file:./target/foobar (H2 2.1)  
[INFO] Successfully validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.020s)  
[INFO] Current version of schema "PUBLIC": 3 
[WARNING] Schema "PUBLIC" has a version (3) that is newer than the latest available migration (2) !  
[INFO] Schema "PUBLIC" is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

I tried to run mvn compile, then mvn flyway:migrate, mvn flyway:info, but I still got the same WARNING and the third job stays in Future state.

I also added a new Java class V4__Add_another_person, then ran mvn compile, mvn flyway:migrate,   but no change to the state of the third job. The new job isn't added to flyway:info output.

Then ran mvn flyway:migrate, and it gave a WARNING shown below.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run a migration, you shouldn't touch any more its script. Here it was identified you did it, as the checksum is different. As long as this code is not pushed to the master branch (and someone run migration), you can remove the latest line from flyway_schema_history and then migrate again.

Comment: I tried to open the console of the embedded H2 database from browser in order to check the content of flyway_schema_history table. but cannot find out what the jdbc URL should be.  It points to user home by default.  I copied the database file to my user home, then I'm able to open the database.

Comment: Now I deleted the database file (foobar.mv.db) from the target folder and repeated the tutorial steps. But somehow flyway could not detect the java class anymore, only migrated the two SQL files.  I tried all sort of cleanup but still not succeed.  I deleted the foobar.mv.db file, then run mvn clean, mvn compile, mvn flyway:migrate, all steps are SUCCESS. The log shows "Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema "PUBLIC", now at version v2 ..." at the end, even I have two java classes on the migration path.

Comment: I tried to do the exercise in a new project, it works.  Just curious what stops flyway to detect the java code in the original project after I did the cleanup.  Somewhere it still has the trace to my unexpected touch on an already migrated file!